# Finding points at which line tangent to curve $y = x^3 - 3x^2 - 2x + 1$ forms equal angles to $x$- and $y$-axes

Tags: calculus, curves, tangent-line

$y = x^{3}-3x^{2}-2x+1$

It's a curve line. I have to find out the points, by which the tangent go through in such a way that, these tangents create equal angles to the both $x$- and $y$-axes. More ***precisely*** ,

Tangent will go through some points, so that, tangent create same equal angle to the both axes. I need to find out the points.

Thanks.

Comment: Wellcome to Math.SE! It would be more helpful and appreciated by our community if 1) you were a little bit more rigorous and 2) you were willing to show us what you've done so far.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος I have only problem that, they said, in that condition, the slope of the tangent will be tan 45 and tan 135, i can't understand , why is this so? I want to see the sketch of this slopes. How the tangent create same angle to the both axis?

Comment: In order to have the same angle between the two axes, you need to draw their two bisectors.

Comment: Does this graph on [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/skmzeadr) help?

Comment: @TobyMak ok i am checking it.

Comment: @TobyMak how can i get help from this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a view, draw coordinates, the line passing point A(a, 0) and B(0, a) has equal angles(45^o) with x and y axis.For formulation the gradient of line is:

$m= tan(180- 45=135)=-1$

and equation of line is $y=-1(x-1)$ or $y=-x+1$.

For your question m=-1 is the gradient of tangents to curve on first and third quarter of coordinate system. For second and forth quarter m=1.Now take derivative of function and equate it to -1, you find a quadratic equation, solving it give the x of required points. Plug them in equation you get y of the points.These are points for tangents in first and third quarters.Do the same with m=1 to find points of tangents on second and forth quarter.